# Selenium Java - How to extract data from a single dropdown (Time field)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Hello people: I have the next dude about extract data from a single calendar field.

I want to take the information (`HH.MM.AM/PM`) from a single date field, but I cannot do it.

I have been trying with the next code:

```java
WebElement currTime = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[31]/div[2]/div/div[1]/" +
        "dv-add-activity-note-form/form/div[1]/div[2]"));

String date = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].textContent;", currTime).toString();

log.info("Time displayed is: " + date);
```

The only result I got it was "Time displayed is: " **and blank**...

This is the part of the HTML:

```
<p-calendar _ngcontent-c75="" appendto="body" class="calendar-field time-field ng-tns-c28-14 ui-inputwrapper-filled ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="start_time" hourformat="12" placeholder="Enter time">
        <span class="ng-tns-c28-14 calendar-field-container ui-calendar ui-calendar-timeonly">
            <!---->
                <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="ng-tns-c28-14 calendar-field-input time-input ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ng-star-inserted" placeholder="Enter time"><!---->

            <!---->
        </span>
    </p-calendar>
```

Could anybody help me?

Comment: show html structure of element, please add it to your question not in comments

Comment: as per your html you are getting what is place holder appearing inside input field,

Comment: `I want to take the information (HH.MM.AM/PM) from a single date field` this is not clear by any sense

Answer (score 0):

1. Your selector assumes some [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)
2. Your HTML code doesn't contain any `<div>`, however it contains an [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) which most probably contains the information you're looking for

So try something like:

```
String date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter time']")).getAttribute("value");
```

this will fetch [value attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp) of the associated input

or even:

```
String date = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p-calendar[@placeholder='Enter time']")).getAttribute("innerText");
```

this approach will get [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) property of the whole `p-calendar` tag

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)